# How to use wrapfigure environment correctly before amsthm environments

Tags: wrapfigure

I defined a theorem environment called `theorem` using the `amsthm` package.

Now I would like it to surround a picture. With this code,

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.3/textwidth}
\includegraphics[...]{...}
\end{wrapfigure}
\begin{theorem}
...
\end{theorem}
```

I received the warning stationary wrapfigure forced to float on input line xxx.

In fact, the picture did "float" and didn't embed in text. I then found that adding

```
\par~\par
```

could solve the problem. However, it created extra space. So how to do this correctly?

Comment: Theorem uses a list, and lists are wrapfigure's Kryptonite.  I would use paracol instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `wrapfig` has its problems, the (rather new) [`wrapstuff` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/wrapstuff) might work (I used it the first time today myself, so I have no idea how robust it is).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{wrapstuff}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapstuff}[type=figure,width=.3\textwidth]
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{A duck.}
\end{wrapstuff}
\begin{theorem}
  Bla bla bla, blub blub blub.
  Bla bla bla, blub blub blub.
  Bla bla bla, blub blub blub.
  Bla bla bla, blub blub blub.
  Bla bla bla, blub blub blub.
  Bla bla bla, blub blub blub.
  Bla bla bla, blub blub blub.
  Bla bla bla, blub blub blub.
  Bla bla bla, blub blub blub.
  Bla bla bla, blub blub blub.
  Bla bla bla, blub blub blub.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Comment: +1: Nice cool new package :). Documentation only in Chinese as of now.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner yep, unfortunately the documentation is not very accessible to me :P But the results look fine so far. It failed to work if I used `\blindduck` as the theorem's text instead of the "Bla bla bla, blub ..." thingy, though.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner found and reported the problem why `\blindduck` didn't work. A paragraph must not start in a group if it doesn't also end in that group. Since `\blindduck` does something like  `\begingroup <text>\endgroup` if it's used without any other options it breaks. But using `\blindduck[-]` would work as then `duckuments` uses a `\par` after `<text>`.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up!